# How to achieve "concept art" graphics?

Tags: shaders, graphics

I'm currently working on a 3D Game and I want a unique graphic style.

Concept Arts have a cool "painted" look. You can clearly see that this picture is painted on a graphic tablet.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnyzB.jpg) - Source: Destiny Concept Arts

How can you achieve that kind of graphics?
I guess you draw the texture just like the concept art and apply a light cel-shader?

Comment: This probably belongs to the graphics SE

Comment: Not a full answer, but it might help you find one: I've sometimes seen this effect called "painterly rendering" and it's a sub niche of the broader topic of non-photorealistic rendering (sometimes NPR for short).

Comment: Thanks! I found a filter called "Kuwahara Filter". Using this as a post processing shader will get you some cool oil painting look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this effect, use the Kuwahara filter as a post processing shader!

[image: Kuwahara Filtering]

There are several ways to implement this algorithm. The Internet should provide sufficient information for the respective purpose.

Edit: I have not tested it yet, but you should also use the Cel shader, so you have less depth in the lighting.